# Django Viewflow - Run the complete worflow

Tags: python, django, workflow, django-viewflow

I've a workflow.

```
class WorkFlow1(Flow):
    start = flow.StartFunction(function1) \
        .Next(this.task2)
    task2 = flow.StartFunction(function2) \
        .Next(this.end)
    end = flow.End()

@flow_start_func
def function1(activation, **kwargs):
    print('Func1 Called.')
    activation.prepare()
    activation.done()
    return activation

@flow_start_func
def function2(activation, **kwargs):
    print('Func2 Called.')
    activation.prepare()
    activation.done()
    return activation
```

I am able to run the workflow programmatically using

```
`WorkFlowClass.start.run()`.
```

It starts the workflow perfectly, but, does not the completes it. The output of the above snippet is

```
Func1 Called
```

Upon completing Node1(start) of workflow, `task2` is not called. Meaning, only first task of the workflow is called, not the subsequent tasks.  Why? And how can I execute the complete workflow?

Answer (score 0):

StartFunction node creates new flow instance. You can't connect one start function to another.

To continue existing flow use `flow.Function` if the function needs to be triggered externally, or `flow.Handler` to immediately proceed.